# export excel rows to individual json files in python

Tags: python, json, excel

My excel file has 500 rows of data. I am trying to get 500 individual JSON files. Each file should have data only from 1 row.
Thank you in advance.

```
import json
import pandas
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel("F:/2/N.csv.xlsx", 
sheet_name='Sheet1')
json_str = 
excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records')
for idx, row in enumerate(json_str):
fpath = str(idx) + ".json"
with open(fpath, "w+") as f:
json.dump(row, f)
```

Comment: Okay, cool. You've told us what you want to do, and you've got some code.  How is this code failing to do what you want? Please read [ask].

Comment: hi.  i added a code i was using.  it was creating 355 json files with only part of the data.  from Excel Sheet to JSON:
 [{"ID":"\u2727 000161 \       first file had only "["   inside.  second "{"  .   3rd "\""   .   4th "I"   .  5th  "D"    and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the pandas `.to_json()` method to convert the dataframe into JSON. This creates a list of JSON strings. If you are trying to get individual JSON files, may I suggest writing something like below.

```
for i, row in enumerate(json_str):
    f = open(f"row_{i}.json", "w")
    f.write(row)
    f.close()
```

This will iterate over the list you created and write a corresponding JSON file. However, there are other ways to do it as well, possibly doing it faster (if you need to scale it up to way more rows). This includes taking advantage of [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org). This means that there is only one JSON file, but with all 500 JSON objects separated by a line break (`\n`). This might help in making things simpler for you as you can use the parameter `lines=True` in the `read_json()` and `to_json()` method within pandas. You might also want to separate the files outside of Python, if you choose to do so, through a shell script to split everything by line breaks.

I hope this helps in some way!

Comment: Hi.  I do need individual JSON files.   my test excel files has 3 rows. 1st is header.  after adding your code, I got  355 json files. inside these files is only character. file row_0   has [ inside.  file row_1  has  {  inside.   . if i use print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', json_str)  , it prints : [{"ID":"\u2727 000161 \u2727","name":"Hello, my name is.    it looks like its splitting only one symbol into each file.